# Not able to use $this->db in custom helper

Tags: php, database, connection, opencart, helper

I have an Opencart store v. 1.5.4 and I've built a custom helper `system/helper/variants.php`. I've created a function to get data from database:

```
function countproductvariant() {

    $newdb = new DB(DB_DRIVER, DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE); $registry->set(‘db’, $db);
    $registry->set(‘newdb’, $newdb);

    $query = $newdb->query("SELECT count(*) as variants FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option po LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "option` o ON (po.option_id = o.option_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "option_description od ON (o.option_id = od.option_id) WHERE po.product_id = '" . (int) $product_id . "' AND od.language_id = '" . (int) $this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' ORDER BY o.sort_order");
        return $query->row['variants'];
}
```

I'm using this in my `controller/product/product.php` like this:

```
$this->data['variantcount'] = countproductvariant();
```

and in `view/.../template/product/product.tpl`

```
echo $variantcount;
```

All I'm getting is a blank screen. If I remove all queries and use `return '0';` it's returning `0` properly.

The only issue is with DB connection. Is this the right way to run DB query?

Has anyone faced this kind of issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: stop doing what are you doing.

Second: read more about MVC. OpenCart is also implemented using MVC and you should follow this standard.

Third: You do not need a helper for this. Just define that method in the `catalog/model/catalog/product.php` file, which is `ModelCatalogProduct` class. The method should look like:

```
public function count_product_variant($product_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS variants FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option po LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "option` o ON (po.option_id = o.option_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "option_description od ON (o.option_id = od.option_id) WHERE po.product_id = '" . (int) $product_id . "' AND od.language_id = '" . (int) $this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' ORDER BY o.sort_order");

    return $query->row['variants'];
}
```

Fourth: In you controller the product model should already be initialized (find the line `$this->load->model('catalog/product');` and place this code somewhere after this line):

```
$this->data['variant_count'] = $this->model_catalog_product->count_product_variant($this->request->get['product_id']);
```

Recommended Fifth: turn on your error reporting so that you are wise of the errors, warnings and notices and can fix them.

That should be it.